# loop with POSIXct vector in R

Tags: r, posixct

i have a vector with POSIXct values

```
time.from <- as.POSIXct('2015-01-01 00:00')
time.to <- as.POSIXct('2015-01-02 00:00')  
time.diff <- as.difftime(75,units='mins')
time.V <- seq(from=time.from,to=time.to, by=time.diff)
```

when i do for loop the values are turned into numerics

```
for (time.i in time.V) {
  print(time.i)
  print(class(time.i))  
}
```

we get numerics

> [1] 1420169400
>   [1] "numeric"

just to check:

```
print(time.V)
```

> [1] "2015-01-01 00:00:00 EST" "2015-01-01 01:15:00 EST" "2015-01-01 02:30:00 EST"
>    ...

```
print(class(time.V))
```

> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

the question is how do i fix this? 
and more important why is this happening?

p.s. sorry for the formatting

Comment: Though the question this duplicates involves a `Date` object instead of a `POSIXct`, the answers are exactly the same.

Comment: thanks for the link, it answers my question, so the solution is: for (i in 1:n) {time.i <- time.V[i]}

Comment: do i delete the question now?

Comment: You can delete it if you want to, but just because your question already has answer doesn't mean it has no value.

Comment: @Henrik, thank you, will do - or more precisely will not do:)